# Count unread emails from multiple outlook mailboxes using EWS c#

Tags: c#, outlook, exchangewebservices

I want to count unread inbox counts from multiple outlook mailboxes (distribution lists) using exchange web services with C#. 
But the code keeps counting **my** **inbox** unread emails and not from the mailboxes I have provided in the code.

Below is my code,

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   getunreademailcount_valid();
   getunreademailcount_invalid();
}
public void getunreademailcount_valid()
{
    ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010);
    service.AutodiscoverUrl("validdocs@abc.com");
    Mailbox mb = new Mailbox("validdocs@abc.com");
    int unreadCount = 0;

    FolderView viewFolders = new FolderView(int.MaxValue) { Traversal = FolderTraversal.Deep, PropertySet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly) };
    ItemView viewEmails = new ItemView(int.MaxValue) { PropertySet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly) };
    SearchFilter unreadFilter = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And, new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.IsRead, false));
    SearchFilter folderFilter = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And, new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(FolderSchema.DisplayName, "AllItems"));

    FindFoldersResults inboxFolders = service.FindFolders(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox,
    new FolderView(int.MaxValue));

    if (inboxFolders.Count() == 0)
    { 
        FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, unreadFilter, viewEmails);
        unreadCount += findResults.Count();

        inboxFolders = service.FindFolders(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, viewFolders);
        foreach (Folder folder in inboxFolders.Folders)
        {
            findResults = service.FindItems(folder.Id, unreadFilter, viewEmails);
            unreadCount += findResults.Count();
            Response.Write(folder.DisplayName + " : " + findResults.Count() + "<br /><br />");
        }
     }
     else 
     {
         foreach (Folder folder in inboxFolders.Folders)
         {
             FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = service.FindItems(folder.Id, unreadFilter, viewEmails);
             Response.Write(folder.DisplayName + " : " + findResults.Count() + "<br /><br />");
         }
     }
}
public void getunreademailcount_invalid()
{
    ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010);

    service.AutodiscoverUrl("invaliddocs@abc.com");
    Mailbox mb = new Mailbox("invaliddocs@abc.com");
   int unreadCount = 0;

    FolderView viewFolders = new FolderView(int.MaxValue) { Traversal = FolderTraversal.Deep, PropertySet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly) };
    ItemView viewEmails = new ItemView(int.MaxValue) { PropertySet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly) };
    SearchFilter unreadFilter = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And, new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.IsRead, false));
    SearchFilter folderFilter = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And, new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(FolderSchema.DisplayName, "AllItems"));

    FindFoldersResults inboxFolders = service.FindFolders(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox,
    new FolderView(int.MaxValue));

    if (inboxFolders.Count() == 0)
    {
        FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, unreadFilter, viewEmails);
        unreadCount += findResults.Count();

        inboxFolders = service.FindFolders(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, viewFolders);
        foreach (Folder folder in inboxFolders.Folders)
        {
             findResults = service.FindItems(folder.Id, unreadFilter, viewEmails);
             unreadCount += findResults.Count();
             Response.Write(folder.DisplayName + " : " + findResults.Count() + "<br />");
         }
     }
     else 
     {
         foreach (Folder folder in inboxFolders.Folders)
         {
            FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = service.FindItems(folder.Id, unreadFilter, viewEmails);
            Response.Write(folder.DisplayName + " : " + findResults.Count() + "<br />");
         }
     }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the FolderId overload to specify the Mailbox you want to access otherwise the Mailbox that belongs to the credentials you are using. You code doesn't make much sense given what you are trying to do eg if all you want to do is access the UnRead Message count on a folder you can use UnreadCount on that folder you don't need to use FindItem eg

```
        Mailbox MailboxYouWantToAccess = new Mailbox("mailbox@yourdomain.com");
        FolderId InboxFolderId = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, MailboxYouWantToAccess);
        Folder InboxFolder = Folder.Bind(service, InboxFolderId);
        Console.WriteLine(InboxFolder.UnreadCount);
```

If you want to use the AllItems folder (that would only be their if the Outlook Desktop client is being used then you can use)

```
         SearchFilter AllItemsSF = new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(FolderSchema.DisplayName, "AllItems");
        ExtendedPropertyDefinition PR_FOLDER_TYPE = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(13825, MapiPropertyType.Integer);
        SearchFilter SearchFoldersOnly = new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(PR_FOLDER_TYPE, 2);
        SearchFilter sfCol = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And) { AllItemsSF, SearchFoldersOnly };
        FolderId SearchRootId = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Root, MailboxYouWantToAccess);
        FolderView fvFolderView = new FolderView(100);
        fvFolderView.Traversal = FolderTraversal.Deep;
        FindFoldersResults ffResults = service.FindFolders(SearchRootId, sfCol, fvFolderView);
        if (ffResults.Folders.Count == 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ffResults.Folders[0].UnreadCount);
        }
```