# Checking number of unread exchange mails with EWS

Tags: powershell, exchangewebservices, powershell-5.0

I'm new using PowerShell, and currently working on a script to check if a shared mailbox contains unread mail.
I am currently trying to get my mails back with the `FindItems()` method.
Here's my code :

```
[int]$nb_unread = 0
[string]$email = "user@domain.org"
[string]$Msg = ""
[int]$Code = 0
[string]$err = ""
Try
{

    Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange\Web Services\2.2\Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll"
    $ews = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeVersion]::Exchange2013)

    $ews.Credentials = New-Object Net.NetworkCredential('user', 'password')
    $ews.AutodiscoverUrl($email, {$true})
    $inbox = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder]::Bind($ews,[Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WellKnownFolderName]::Inbox)
    $view = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemView(10)
    $mailItems = $inbox.FindItems($view)
    $mails | ForEach {$_.Load()}

    foreach($mail in $mails)
    {
        if($mail.isread -eq $false)
        {
            nb_unread += 1
        }
    }
    if (nb_unread -eq 0)
    {
        $Msg = "OK;No unread mail."
    }
    else
    {
        $Msg = ("NOOK;Unread mails : " -f $nb_unread)
    }
}
Catch
{
    $Code = 2
    $Msg = ( "CRITICAL: erreur(s) d'execution du script : {0}" -f $err )
}
```

I got this error when my scripts execute the '$mailItems = $inbox.FindItems($view)' line.

```
Exception lors de l'appel de «FindItems» avec «1» argument(s): «The request failed. Le serveur distant a retourné une
erreur: (501) Non implémenté.»
Au caractère Ligne:16 : 5
+     $mailItems = $inbox.FindItems($view)
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ServiceRequestException
```

Rough English translation

```
Exception when calling "FindItems" with "1" argument (s): "The request failed. The remote server returned an error: (501) Not implemented. 
At Line:16 Char:5 
+ $ mailItems = $inbox.FindItems ($ view) 
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 
    + CategoryInfo: NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException 
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId: ServiceRequestException
```

Comment: And your problem is what exactly? How does this code not work? You have a huge try block and no catch block which should trigger a syntax error. Is the code erroring silently from an empty catch?

Comment: Well, my script crashes when it executes the FindItem.
My message is updated with the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[A related question in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33020084/count-unread-emails-from-multiple-outlook-mailboxes-using-ews-c-sharp) starts off on the same foot as you. You do not need to query every mail in the box to see if it is unread. There is a data folder property that already has that information for you: [`UnreadCount`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.folder.unreadcount(v=exchg.80).aspx)

```
# Get the Mailbox ID of the Inbox folder.
$inboxFolderID = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderId]::new([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WellKnownFolderName]::Inbox,$MailAddress)

# Bind to the inbox folder.
$boundFolder = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder]::Bind($objExchange,$inboxFolderID)
$boundFolder.UnreadCount
```

In your case you should just have to use `$inbox.UnreadCount` and remove your loop logic.

Comment: Thanks,
the $inbox.UnreadCount call does what i need in my script.

Answer (score 0):

I go by a different aproach:

```
$inbox_mails = $Inbox.FindItems($Inbox.TotalCount)
$inbox_mails | where-object IsRead -eq $false
```

And then pipe that either into format table, or wrap it into `().count` or do something else with it.

Like:

```
($inbox_mails | where-object IsRead -eq $false).count
```

Also, where does your `$sfCollection`variable come from?

Comment: This is a very bad approach. You are essentially requesting all mails in the current folder. Nice for small mailboxes. A disaster for a mailbox with thousands of items in it.

Comment: Yes i know now, it wasn't until i saw the other answer i became aware of the UnreadCount property.